# Error: The database connection must be open to store files at GridFSStorage._handleFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, multer, gridfs

I want to add file with multer using nodejs/angular app. The same code(nodejs part) works perfectly fine on nodejs/react-redux app.

Here's server.js code( with message route which is the most important one):

```
const express = require('express'); 
const cors = require('cors'); 
const path = require('path'); 
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
require('dotenv').config(); 
require('./modules/auth');
const passport = require('passport');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// #6 Initialize an Express application 
const app = express();

// Bodyparser MiddlewareFirst way
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb', extended: false}));

// Bodyparser Middleware - second way
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors()); 


app.use(cookieSession({
  name: 'session',
  keys: ['key1', 'key2']
}))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const db = process.env.mongoURI;

// Connect to Mongo
mongoose 
  .connect(db, { 
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true, 
    useFindAndModify: false }) // Adding new mongo url parser 
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...')) 
  .catch(err => console.log(err)); 

app.use('/api/messages', require('./routes/api/messages'));
app.use('/api/posts', require('./routes/api/posts'));
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/auth'));


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => { 
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html')) 
}); 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000; 
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

I also tried removing/commenting all things like modules/auth, all passport part code and other routes, but it still doesn't work.(When console.log connection, I seen that there's only user model/Schema/collection included, even that I have three models(and three routes). So I also tried to add file with auth route, but it also doesn't work.

So now I'll show my message route(which works correctly, when I don't add any files, so connection must be open).

routes/api/messages.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
const { initStorage, initUpload } = require('../../modules/multerModule');

const conn = mongoose.connection;
Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;

// console.log(conn);
// Init gfs
let gfs;

conn.once('open', () => {
  // Init stream
  gfs = Grid(conn.db);
  gfs.collection(collectionName);
});

const collectionName = 'messages';
const bucketName = 'messages';

console.log(conn);

const storage = initStorage(conn, bucketName);

const upload = initUpload(storage);


// File Model
const Message = require('../../models/message');

// @route GET /
// @desc Loads form
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Message.find()
    .sort({ date: 1 })
    .then(messages => res.json(messages))
});


// @route POST /upload
// @desc  Uploads file and object to DB
router.post('/', upload.single('message'), (req, res) => {

  const fileImage = (req.body.fileImage == 'true');
  console.log(fileImage);
  if (req.files !== undefined) {
    const { files } = req;
    const { id, filename } = files[0];
    const newMessage = new Message({
      files_id: id,
      fileImage: req.body.fileImage,
      path: '/api/messages/image/' + filename,
      content: req.body.content
      // Grab the file id that was stored in the database by the storage engine as the messages to your file
    })
    newMessage.save().then(messages => res.json(messages));
  }
  else {
    const newMessage = new Message({
      files_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      path: req.body.path,
      fileImage: req.body.fileImage,
      content: req.body.content
      // Grab the file id that was stored in the database by the storage engine as the messages to your file
    })
    newMessage.save().then(messages => res.json(messages));
  }
});

// ... here's also put and gets filename routes, but that's not important right now

module.exports = router;
```

and my storage functions:

modules/multerModule.js

```
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage');

// Create storage engine
const initStorage = (conn, bucketName) => new GridFsStorage({
  db: conn,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: bucketName
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});

// Create upload module
const initUpload = (storage) => multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, callback) {
    const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    if (ext !== '.png' && ext !== '.jpg' && ext !== '.gif' && ext !== '.jpeg') {
      return callback(new Error('Only images are allowed'))
    }
    callback(null, true)
  }
});

module.exports = { initStorage, initUpload };
```

I have tried everything, if you have any idea why it isn't working please share with me.

Heres some screenshots of my connection data:

[image: First difference]

[image: Second difference]

I've did one change in my code and get new error, but it's going forward:

I've imported routes before I used them:

```
const messages = require('./routes/api/messages');
const posts = require('./routes/api/posts');
const auth = require('./routes/auth');

//...

app.use('/api/messages', messages);
app.use('/api/posts', posts);
app.use('/auth', auth);
```

And I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isConnected' of undefined
```

which leads to initStorage function:

```
const conn = mongoose.connection;
Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;

// console.log(conn);
// Init gfs
let gfs;

conn.once('open', () => {
  // Init stream
  gfs = Grid(conn.db);
  gfs.collection(collectionName);
});

const collectionName = 'messages';
const bucketName = 'messages';

console.log(conn);

const storage = initStorage(conn, bucketName); // here comes the error, but it can be connected with conn variable.
```

And the initStorage function(I will show it again):

```
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage');

// Create storage engine
const initStorage = (conn, bucketName) => new GridFsStorage({
  db: conn,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: bucketName
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer, however I don't know why some thing in mongoose connection is broken:

in initStorage I just did it directly, that and its working perfectly:

```
// Create storage engine
const initStorage = (url, bucketName) => new GridFsStorage({
  url: url,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: bucketName
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

So my question is, why this mongoose connection in server.js is broken?